# MySQL Installation Trouble

Tags: mysql

I've just tried to install mysql on a root server I recently rented.
I think the problem is MySQL was already installed on there.
Anyway when running "sudo mysql_secure_installation" it returns this:

Enter password for user root:
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Any help on that?
I've browsed the internet für half an hour now and everyone has a slightly different problem or "solution". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the MySQL daemon running?

Comment: the service is not running

Comment: How do I check that?